# SoxNotInstalled exception raised when importing pyaudioconvert

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okXg5.png)As can be seen in the traceback the exception occurs when pyaudioconvert is imported. How can this be fixed?

Traceback below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\320052863\PycharmProjects\Test\venv\lib\site-packages\pyaudioconvert\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    assert(bool_which('sox'))
AssertionError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/320052863/PycharmProjects/Test/hello.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyaudioconvert
  File "C:\Users\320052863\PycharmProjects\Test\venv\lib\site-packages\pyaudioconvert\__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    raise SoxNotInstalled()
pyaudioconvert.SoxNotInstalled
```

Comment: Please format your question so it is not just code (or error message in your case). Do you have SoX installed? [pyaudioconvert lists it as a requirement.](https://pypi.org/project/pyaudioconvert/)

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, you need to install [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/).

It is also listed as a requirement for [`pyaudioconvert`](https://pypi.org/project/pyaudioconvert/).

Comment: can you please suggest how to install SOX. beacause its not installing in command line. that's why?

Comment: I don't know what your operating system but you can download it [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sox/files/sox/). What exactly is the error?

Comment: import pyaudioconvert
import scipy
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Speak Anything :")
    audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        text = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print("You said : {}".format(text))
    except:
        print("Sorry could not recognize what you said")







This is my code for speech recognition.

Comment: The error you have while installing. I suggest you edit what goes wrong when trying to install SoX into the main post.